# How to set the orthographic camera with babylon.js?

Tags: camera, orthographic

I'm struggling with using the orthographic camera. I don't know how to set the

- orthoTop
- orthoBottom
- orthoLeft
- orthoRight

Can anyone be so kind to help me understand how to calculate these values? Where do these values come from?

One similar question is here:
http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/28449-blender-orthographic-export/